# WinAPI Documentation within visual studio 2012

Tags: c, winapi, visual-studio-2012

All I want from my Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, is to have the WinAPI documentation (OFFLINE), as it is on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx.

I selected View Help from Help Menu Bar, and when I want to search a function from WinAPI, it gives me only one function (or more), but from Microsoft Framework 4.5 / 4.0 / 3.5. I downloaded the Visual Studio 2008 documentation, but this doesn't work on Visual Studio 2012 (I can't see it).

I have the next following contents installed on my Visual Studio:
http://imageshack.com/a/img854/5902/hdjm.png

Comment: VS2010-express has the menu option "help->manage help setting" which brings up an assistant allowing you to install help docs also from the net to a local folder. This feature might also be available in your VS2012.

Comment: You've got the wrong radio button selected.  Click "Online" to see what documents you can download to your machine.  Change the setting for "Windows Desktop App Development" and let it trundle.

Comment: There's no Windows Desktop App Development on Online Source ... Only: "API Reference for Windows Store apps", "Windows Azure", "Windows Driver Development", "Windows Debugging", "Windows Embedded Compact 2013"

Comment: I'm still using WIN32.HLP. Win32 has not changed enough to call that documentation obsolete.

Comment: There's a bug report for this here on MS connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/844141/windows-desktop-app-development-book-missing-from-downloadable-local-documentation

Comment: This seems to have been fixed in part (see ["Windows Desktop App Development" book missing from downloadable local documentation](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/844141)). For those topics missing, a new Connect report is open ([Some topics are missing from downloadable offline help](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1080276)),

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft shows this issue as "Closed as fixed"](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/844141/windows-desktop-app-development-book-missing-from-downloadable-local-documentation).